# How to handle exception using servlet so that if user leave a field blank in that case it take default value by

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

```
age<input type="number" name="age">
Price<input type="number" name="price">
```

Now in servlet I'm doing

```
int age=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
double price=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price");
```

Now if user is entering the value, then it is working fine but when user is not entering it is giving exception. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add below logic for name and similarly you can add for rest of the fields as well

```
String ageVal = req.getParameter("age");
String priceVal = req.getParameter("price");

int age = 0;
double  price = 0;

if ((ageVal == null) || (ageVal.equals(""))) {
    System.out.println(("PROVIDE STUDENT NUMBER...");
} else {
    try {
        age = Integer.parseInt("ageVal");
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
       System.out.println("NumberFormatException="+nfe.getStackTrace());
    }
}

if ((priceVal == null) || (priceVal.equals(""))) {
    System.out.println(("PROVIDE STUDENT NUMBER...");
} else {
    try {
        price = Integer.parseInt("priceVal");
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
       System.out.println("NumberFormatException="+nfe.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please write it down for any one like age ...because i have already tried this...

Comment: try this one :)

Comment: thank you very much for the support and your valuable time i will try this out

Comment: np, please accept the answer and upvote if you think its useful